# Firebase authWithOAuthPopup returns TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE when using PhoneGap Cloud Build

Tags: cordova, firebase, phonegap-plugins

I have had success using the authWithOAuthPopup in my html5 application but when I recently created a phoneGap build, it fails on Android.

I have done the obvious thus far that Ive found from other sources:

Added sources to config.xml:

```
<access origin="*.firebaseio.*" />
<access origin="https://auth.firebase.com" />
```

Ive also added the InAppBrowser plugin:

`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />`

In my test, Im able to call window.open on my phone and get another web page to come up so I know the plugin seems to work.

However, when I use the firebase code, Im unable to get any Auth method to work.

Here is some sample code:

```
rootRef.authWithOAuthPopup(provider, function (err, user) {
if (err) {
if (err.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
// fails here
}
}});
```

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: I believe I found my issue..Even though I havent taken advantage of any of the phonegap "feature", I still had to include this line

Comment: `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>`

Comment: Even though I dont include the phonegap.js script in my source files or take advantage of it. Once I added this line, the popup works.

Comment: Great to hear that you've figured it out. Can you post the solution as an answer and then (when SO allows it) accept it? You'll gain some reputation points for that and it'll make it clearer to others that your problem is solved (without them having to read the comment thread).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding this line:
`<script src="phonegap.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below link

> ```
> <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
> ```

Does not work for

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
```

even after adding

```
<access origin="*.firebaseio.*" />
<access origin="https://auth.firebase.com" />
```

Comment: Hi--I'm not entirely clear on how this answers the original question. Would you mind editing your answer to explain more clearly? If this is asking a new question, please press the Ask Question button on the site to make a new post; you can link to this page if you'd like. Thanks!

Comment: its neither a question nor an answer , but letting people know that this solution does not work for some people like me .