# getting stuck ,Log in with facebook with firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

i try to login with facebook in firebase using java script and html. i also create a facebook application and set app secret and app id in firebase dashbord.
and all the other setting in facebook app that firebase said in their doc
but im getting this.

```
<html>
       <head>
       <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js'></script>
       <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div id='messagesDiv'></div>
    <input type='text' id='nameInput' placeholder='Name'>
    <input type='text' id='messageInput' placeholder='Message'>
    <script>
      var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://fiery-inferno-9432.firebaseio.com/');
          myDataRef.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
          } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
          }
        });

        myDataRef.authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook", function(error, authData) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("Ridi Failed!", error);
          } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
          }
        });





        $('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          var name = $('#nameInput').val();
          var text = $('#messageInput').val();
          myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
          $('#messageInput').val('');
        }
      });
      myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
      });
      function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
        $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
        $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

im getting 
 Login Failed! Error: There are no login transports available for the requested method.code: "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE"message: "There are no login transports available for the requested method."stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }**proto**: dconstructor: function Error() { [native code] }message: ""name: "Error"toString: function toString() { [native code] }**proto**: Object

Comment: What platform are you using? Popup authentication is not available in browser environments that don't support it.

Comment: See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158714/firebase-authwithoauthpopup-returns-transport-unavailable-when-using-phonegap-cl) of which this may be a duplicate. The currently accepted answer suggests adding a .js lib to correct the issue.

Comment: @RobDiMarco im using chrome on windows 8.1 . also tried on firefox. HTML file are located on my local computer –

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the problem. i must run the html file by running a file server
 simply by this on cmd

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

and then run html by 
http://localhost/test.html

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html:

> Note: Browser popups and redirects are not available on all platforms
>   or browser environments. Popups are not available in Chrome for iOS,
>   iOS Preview Panes, or local, file:// URLs.

Also, when authenticating via popup on PhoneGap / Cordova apps, including `cordova.js` and the `InAppBrowser` plugin in the scope of the page are both required.

Comment: im using chrome on windows 8.1 . also tried on firefox. HTML file are located on my local computer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running my page via server on localhost instead of running the file directly from file system.