# Firebase: TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE error for Facebook login in node.js

Tags: firebase

I am trying to implement social login (Facebook and Twitter) on the server side (node.js). However, it is constantly giving me a "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE" error. Any ideas?

Code:

```
function authHandler(error, authData) {
    if (error) {
        res.send(error);
    }
    else {
        res.send("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    }
};

var args = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    provider: req.body.provider
};

if (args.provider=="password") {
    ref.authWithPassword({email: args.email, password: args.password}, authHandler);
}
//Provider can be only facebook or twitter
else  {
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup(args.provider, authHandler); //Doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Can you include code? It would be useful to know how you're trying to authenticate (i.e. which transport)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error creating user: { \[Error: There are no login transports available for the requested method.\] code: 'TRANSPORT\_UNAVAILABLE' }](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541571/error-creating-user-error-there-are-no-login-transports-available-for-the-r)

Comment: And if not that one, then this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158714/firebase-authwithoauthpopup-returns-transport-unavailable-when-using-phonegap-cl (i.e. adding phonegap.js)

Comment: The above question deals in phonegap not node.js and the one before that uses login with email and password. That works fine. What doesn't work is the social login (in node.js).

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an issue with the browser using a popup or a local file trying to access a resource to which it doesn't have permission. There's likely nothing wrong with your code as is, but you need to handle this edge case somehow.

See the docs here for a workaround to this issue: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html

> TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE The requested login method is not available in the user's browser environment. Popups are not available in Chrome for iOS, iOS Preview Panes, or local, file:// URLs. Redirects are not available in PhoneGap / Cordova, or local, file:// URLs.

The workaround for facebook (same with Twitter/Google login, just swap the name in quotes below) is to have a fallback to using a redirect rather than a popup (presuming you're using a popup here):

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
// prefer pop-ups, so we don't navigate away from the page

ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
      // fall-back to browser redirects, and pick up the session
      // automatically when we come back to the origin page
      ref.authWithOAuthRedirect("google", function(error) { /* ... */ });
    }
  } else if (authData) {
    // user authenticated with Firebase
  }
}
```